# How to force/wrap <img> inside div?

Tags: html, image, css, href

I have a Wrapper that contains a bunch of thumbnails for a photo gallery with fancybox.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href><img thumbnail></a>
    <a href><img thumbnail></a>
    <a href><img thumbnail></a>
    ...
</div>
```

The wrapper has a defined `width`. The number of thumbnails varies from 1 to ... The problem is that the space inside the wrapper is only for a maximum count of 7 thumbnails. So all thumbnails over 7 will be displayed outside. How can I archive that all thumbnails will remain inside the wrapper `' so that all over 7 are kind of hidden?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css to your `.wrapper` div

```
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have You Tried With

overflow:hidden !important;(css).

Answer (score 0):

you can add **scroll** to your .wrapper.it can be achieved by adding **overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;** to your .wrapper. which will keep your wrapper size same and you are possible to add any no of images as you need.

```css
.wrapper{
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background:yellow;
  }
img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<a href><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg" thumbnail></a>
<a href><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg" thumbnail></a>
<a href><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg" thumbnail></a>
<a href><img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg"thumbnail></a>
<a href><img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg"thumbnail></a>
<a href><img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg"thumbnail></a>
<a href><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg"thumbnail></a>
<a href><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg"thumbnail></a>
<a href><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg"thumbnail></a>
<a href><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg"thumbnail></a>
<a href><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg"thumbnail></a>
<a href><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2JkH.jpg"thumbnail></a>

</div>
```